# ASP.net Web Application project maintaining release and builds

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, versioning, azure-devops

We are a small team, working on a ASP.net Web Application project, following is the solution structure,

Solution:

1. Project: Data Access Layer
2. Project: Model Layer
3. Project: Business Layer
4. Project: Web Application Project

For source code repository, we are using Visual Studio Online, since team is small so we are using the Free version.

We are now trying to maintain the proper version for each release. Currently we publish (using publish tool Visual Studio) in a folder, then manually copy and paste files on server Website folder. So right now, the web application's DLL file is having version 1.0.0.0 all the time.

Now we want to use the VSO Build Feature, and each time when we run the build, we want this to happen.

1. Compiled website
2. Full code should (all projects) also be copied along with published files
3. The website DLL's build number should be increased automatically

I am NOT sure if all the above can be done on build or is there any other procedure. Can someone please point us in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That can all be fine with the build on VSO. If you are using the XAML build you don't need anything else. Just configured a new build and out It at your solution. You will then get versioned output. To get the build output to have the version number incremented you will need to use powershell and call that during the build.

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2014/01/11/customize-tfs-2013-build-with-powershell-scripts/

Comment: Thanks @MrHinsh for you answer, I currently looking into auto increment thing. But one thing which I am unable to achieve is to copy the full source code along with published website (point #2). Can you please shade some light on it?

Comment: Why would you want the code? If you need It you can copy It across with powershell.